# How to use variance-covariance matrix to estimate the confidence interval of regression coefficient?

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, standard-error

guys

I'm interested in multivariate regression and I basically understand the maximum likelihood method to get the point estimation of regression coefficients. However, it still has not been figured out how to get the interval estimation. I searched the Internet and many focus on variance-covariance matrix. I would like to understand the rational and proof behind but current no luck. Could you please give me some guidance? Thank you.